# How to make authorized "post" request strapi graphql apollo nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo, strapi

I am building an ecommerce website using strapi, apollo, graphql, nextjs, when an authenticated users ordering they need to send jwt token using headers but I am little confused how to do that. Here is my code on apollographql playground.

```
mutation Mutation($data: OrderInput!) {
```

createOrder(data: $data) {
data {
id
attributes {
name
phone
products {
data {
id
attributes {
price
name
media {
data {
attributes {
url
}
}
}
}
}
}
status
details
createdAt
user {
data {
attributes {
username
}
}
}
}
}
}
}[image]
[image]

When I do that it is giving following error.

```
{
```

"errors": [
{
"message": "Forbidden access",
"extensions": {
"error": {
"name": "ForbiddenError",
"message": "Forbidden access",
"details": {}
},
"code": "FORBIDDEN"
}
},
{
"message": "Forbidden access",
"extensions": {
"error": {
"name": "ForbiddenError",
"message": "Forbidden access",
"details": {}
},
"code": "FORBIDDEN"
}
}
],

Without authorisation its working fine, but I do not know how to insert jwt token

[image: its my order content type, has relation with user]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. You probably inserted an expired token. Have you tried turning on the create permission for authenticated role?

Comment: Yes, I set all the necessary permissions, and tryed using new token, but no luck. I added  an image of my content type you can see on above

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue by allowing "find" method in user permission tab.[image]